# Easier way of seeing output in Wing IDE

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_excel(location, sheetname="Sheet1")
df2 =  pd.read_excel(location, sheetname="Sheet2")
combine = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on=['UserID'], right_on=['UserID'])
```

I basically have to type `df1`, `df2` and `combine` in the Python shell to get the output. Note that this is in the Wing IDE. Is there way of seeing the output tables in an "Excel format" similar to RStudio?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this piece of code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    df1 = pd.read_excel(location, sheetname="Sheet1")
    df2 = pd.read_excel(location, sheetname="Sheet2")
    combine = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on=['UserID'], right_on=['UserID'])
```

I'm not sure about getting the output in an "Excel" format as I haven't worked with pandas, but this code is similar to having a "main" function which will automatically run if you are running this file as the source (i.e., not importing it in another file). As a result, you shouldn't have to type `df1`, `df2` and `combine` in the Wing IDE console as this will run when you hit **Execute**.

Hope that helps.